# how can i change the order of two components within the same slot in spartacus? with hybris

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to modify the default PDP(ProductDetailsPageTemplate) page that comes with Spartacus but I don't know how.

I'm new with Spartacus. I want to do the following:

1. Change the order of two components
2. move `addToCart` button component before the `variant` component within the summary slot.
   I can't get it done. I've tried creating a new custom component but it didn't work, changing the `layout-config` and nothing.

PDP image:

[image: PDP image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the order by changing the position of the cms component in the backoffice.

In the backoffice, navigate to 'WCMS' > 'Content Slot' > 'ProductSummarySlot' for the catalog you are using.
I am assuming it is apparel from the picture, so change the 'Online' catalog if you want it to be rendered right away, or 'Staged' and re-sync the catalog.

From there, under 'properties' and 'components', you can just swap the positioning of 'Product Variant Selector' and 'Product Add To Cart' by dragging them.

Comment: thank you so much!